# Which tags should be used for image recognition?

Tags: discussion, tags

Given the following question:

- [How does Pinterest decipher what's on unmarked pictures and categorize them?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1687/8)

which tags should be suitable for it in terms of the image recognition?

[image-recognition](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-recognition), [computer-vision](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision) or [visual-search](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-search)?

Should we stick only to [image-recognition](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-recognition), or the other can be useful in some cases as well?

If multiple, what's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Categorizing things in pictures as certain types of objects definitely sounds like [image-recognition](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-recognition) to me. After all, the computer is supposed to *recognize* what the thing is and then put them into categories.

Two of the three existing questions in [computer-vision](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision) don't really seem to be related to computerized image comprehension at all. The last - the question you linked - would, in my opinion, be better served by [image-recognition](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-recognition). [computer-vision](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision) seems more appropriate for questions involving the AI moving around and continually *seeing* the world and the states of the things in it (like self-driving cars do), which involves more than just figuring out what objects are present.

Since [visual-search](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-search) doesn't exist yet, I think we should wait for a compelling distinction between it and [image-recognition](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-recognition) before creating it.

Comment: The visual-search was applied to the linked question, because it was relating to search using visual data.

Comment: Interesting. I don't see it on the question, and the tag says there are no questions tagged with it. (I blame caching.)

Comment: I mean it was [edited out](http://ai.stackexchange.com/posts/1687/revisions), so that's why I'm asking whether we should burn this tag.

Comment: @kenorb Ah. In the absence of a notable difference between it and [image-recognition], my inclination would be to leave it gone. (I wasn't the one who removed it, though.)

Comment: @BenN No, I was. :P And I did leave a comment, saying that I thought that [image-recognition] covered it all. (And since it was a *suggested* edit, kenorb could have rejected it...)

Comment: I accepted it, I agree that image-recognition covers that, so no worries, but I wanted to double check whether this tag could be useful for that kind of questions or other. In some studies they use 'visual-search' as a keyword. It indicates you're using image recognition for searching, not only classification.